# Separate Ajax Calls in the Same JS file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a few buttons on one page in which I need different ajax calls for. In Chrome, this is working perfectly, but in Firefox, it seems that it's always pulling that first ajax call in the file, no matter what button is pressed. The main difference between the two calls is the action. Do I need to fix my code in order for Firefox to recognize the different calls/actions?

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item > a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var profCategory = $(this).data('category')
    
    $.ajax({
      url: wpProfAjax.ajaxProfUrl,
      data: { action: 'profFilter', profCategory: profCategory },
      type: 'post',
      success: function(result) {
        $("#professionals-container").hide().html(result).fadeIn(1000);
        $(".misha_loadmore").hide();
      },
      error: function(result) {
        console.warn(result);
      }
    });
  });

  $('div.sidebar-filter form').find('button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $('#title').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: wpProfAjax.ajaxProfUrl,
      data: { action: 'lnFilter', title: title },
      type: 'post',
      success: function(result) {
          var profs = $(result).find('.professionals-column');
          if(profs.length < 9){
              $('.misha_loadmore').css('display', 'none');
              $('#page').val('1');
          }
          else{
             $('.misha_loadmore').css('display', 'block');   
          }
          $("#professionals-container").hide().html(result).fadeIn(1000);
      },
      error: function(result) {
        console.warn(result);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: So this is the click function that's always fired in Firefox `$(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item > a', function(e){ //code }`, no matter which button has been pressed? Or what do you mean?

Comment: u need to use dynamic ids to each button and add call to that. please paste your full code like html and how you placing buttons on page and what is difference in each ajax call

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item > a', function(e){
change to                   
 $( '.js-filter-item > a').on('click',function(e){